# Magento 1.9 - out of stock RSS feed not working / not accessible

Tags: magento-1.9, rss

I am running a Magento webstore. Everything seems to work as expected. I would like to use the "Low stock RSS feed", but I can't get it working. What happens:

- clicking the RSS link in admin menu opens a new tab and requires me to authenticate. I cannot authenticate with my administrator user or any other user. The auth windows just returns everytime.

Do I have to insert additional code or configuration parameters to get the Low Stock Notification RSS feed to work? I searched the web and magento stx, but couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user and new user role. Only give access to sales and catalog, then use these credentials to access your feeds.